# JSON.NET Add/edit children

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm currently trying to read a JSON document from the webserver (it's a physical json file) and check for changes against my database. In other words, I need to sync the json document and the database every night or so.

For this I'm using JSON.NET, which I believe is the way to go when working with JSON in C# (?) The .NET platform is version 3.5.

So far I am able to read the document and get values from it.

My JSON looks like this:

```
{"members":[

{"member":
    {
        "id":"4282",
        "status":"1931",
        "aktiv":"1",
        "firmanavn":"firmname1",
        "firmaUrl":"www.firmsite.com",
        "firmaUrlAlternativ":"",
        "firmaSidstKontrolleretDato":"30-08-2010",
        "firmaGodkendelsesDato":"07-03-2002"
    }
},
{"member":
    {
        "id":"4283",
        "status":"1931",
        "aktiv":"1",
        "firmanavn":"firmname2",
        "firmaUrl":"www.firmsite.com",
        "firmaUrlAlternativ":"",
        "firmaSidstKontrolleretDato":"30-08-2010",
        "firmaGodkendelsesDato":"18-12-2000"
    }
}, .... and so on
]}
```

And my C# code is as follows:

```
using (TextReader reader = File.OpenText(Server.MapPath("~/members.json")))
    {
        JsonTextReader jsonreader = new JsonTextReader(reader);
        var o = JObject.ReadFrom(jsonreader);
        jsonreader.Close();
        JObject obj = JObject.Parse(o.ToString());

        JArray items = (JArray)obj["members"];
        var members = Member.GetAllAsList();

        JObject item;
        JToken token;

        List<string> currentIds = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
        {
            item = (JObject)items[i];
            token = item.First;

            while (token != null)
            {
                //ltTest.Text += ((JProperty)token).Value["firmanavn"].ToString() + System.Environment.NewLine;
                currentIds.Add(((JProperty)token).Value["id"].ToString());
                token = token.Next;
            }
        }

        foreach (var member in members)
        {
            if (!currentIds.Contains(member.Id.ToString()))
            {
                ltTest.Text += member.Text;
            }
        }
    }
```

So basically, there's three scenarios now:

- A members information has been changed in the database: I need to find the member in the JSON document and update the corresponding fields
- A member has been deleted from the database: I need to find the member in the JSON document and delete it.
- A member has been added to the database: I need to add that member to the JSON document.

So, is anyone familiar with JSON.NET to give a hint (or perhaps some code-examples?) on how to achieve this? I barely made it to actually read the json document from the server, so this seems like an uphill battle for me at the moment.

Comment: You realize you can serialize and deserialize to/from json natively, right? Its just like Xml Serialization.  From there, you're just working with objects in .net.  No weird API to learn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Json.net has a thing called Linq-to-JSON, which according to the website is:

> LINQ to JSON isn't a LINQ provider but rather an API for working with
>   JSON objects. The API has been designed with LINQ in mind to enable
>   the quick creation and querying of JSON objects.

So it supports LINQ querying which, I haven't used Linq-to-JSON but i am sure, will fulfill all three of your requirements.

For reference and how-tos please follow these links:
http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2008/02/11/linq-to-json-beta.aspx
http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/

Comment: Hi Waqas, the linq-to-json was what did the trick for me! Thanks a bunch :) Not I'm just left with a serializing/deserializing question which I will make another post about. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

To fulfill your requirements, I would suggest the following steps:

- Parse your JSON feed into easy to use JSON Object just like you did
- In order to get your requirements fulfilled, the easiest is probably doing table to table comparison using SQL.

  - Create a staging tables to put the JSON data in
  - Convert the data in JSON feed into Relational form. In your case, it is pretty straightforward of creating table `MEMBER` with the 8 columns

From there, you issue SQL queries that are matching with your three cases which is:

- *A members information has been changed in the database: I need to find the member in the JSON document and update the corresponding fields*

  In order to do this, issue a SQL Query that compare each field, use the resultset to update the JSON
- *A member has been deleted from the database: I need to find the member in the JSON document and delete it.*

  Issue a SQL Query doing comparison using NOT IN comparator from original tables comparing with the `Member` tables that you just created. From here you will get collection of IDs from the result set that you could use to delete the appropriate JSON Object
- *A member has been added to the database: I need to add that member to the JSON document.*

  Do the reverse of the previous steps. Issue a SQL Query comparing data that is in the database but not in the `Member` table. Use the resultset to add to the JSON Object

At the end of the process, you would have the JSON Object that is representing the sync between the two

Comment: Hi momo, thanks a lot for you thorough description - this would definately be the way to go, but I forgot (sorry about that!) to mention, that the website is running Umbraco where querying the DB is a big nono because of all the caching and relations. Anyway, thanks again for your time :)